# Replacing integers to string

Tags: java

I am trying to print some alphabets here, I am new to java and can't figure out where to add the alphabets in pattern.

```
package prints;

public class Pattern {
  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int rows = 6;
    int[] diff = {0,1,3,5,7,9,11};
    int blank = 0;
    int b = 0;
    int temp;
    
    for(int i = rows; i >= 1; --i){
        
        blank = diff[b++];

        if(blank == 0)
            temp = i-1;
        else
            temp = i;

        for(int j = 1; j <= i; j++){
            
            System.out.print(" "+ j + " ");
        }
    
        for(int s = 0; s < blank; s++){
            System.out.print("   ");
        }
        
        for(int k = temp; k >= 1; --k){
            System.out.print(" " + k + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();            
    }
  }
}
```

this is the code. trouble in switching languages.

Answer (score 1):

Integers are numbers, not characters. Therefore, they cannot be "converted".

You could however try using a char. For example:

```
char h = (char) 72;
```

Then print the result:

```
String.valueOf(h);
```